# How to display date on a separate line

Tags: tableau-api

**Question**:
I used the custom date format(e.g., 4/22 11:00), and display these dates on the horizontal axis, however I want to split the date format( 4/22 11:00) into two lines,for instance,

```
4/22
11:00
```

**Why do I want this**
Date( 4/22 ) and time(11:00) are displayed at the distinct lines, which can easily differentiate date from time.

**What did I try**
I found an item "Wrap" in "Alignment", but it can't work.

Comment: Have you looked into DATETRUNK ? I found something that might start getting you in the right direction.  http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/using-datetrunc-trend-lines

Answer (score 0):

Better late than ever, if you're still interested, there's a way.

You need to create a new calculated field, to generate the labels as you wish. If the field you're working if is called Date (for instance), you should do:

```
STR(DAY([Date])) + '/' + STR(MONTH([Date])) + '/' + STR(YEAR([Date]))
+
'
'
+
IF LEN(STR(DATEPART('hour',[Date]))) == 1
THEN '0' + STR(DATEPART('hour',[Date]))
ELSE STR(DATEPART('hour',[Date]))
END
+
':'
+
IF LEN(STR(DATEPART('minute',[Date]))) == 1
THEN '0' + STR(DATEPART('minute',[Date]))
ELSE STR(DATEPART('minute',[Date]))
END
```

First line is just to get the date on a d/m/y format. Then the trick is to add + '' separated by blank space (tried \n, but it prints "\n" instead of breaking the line)
The second part is to generate the hh:mm (you can use the same logic to get a dd/mm/yyyy format for the date). Basically it adds a zero if the hour or minute is a one digit number.